# Can SMD pick and place machine work without a breakaway rail?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I designed a 4 layer PCB.  SMD components are on one side only.

When I order bare board directly (no breakway rails, no panelization) it costs $100.  When I order 20 pieces (there are 2 PCBs in each panel) with a breakway rail panelization including breakways, the price is like 358 dollars.

Can the SMD pick and and place machine work without a breakaway rail? Placed on the rail directly from the edges and individually.  The nearest SMD component is 2mm away from the board edge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, your price difference doesn't make a lot of sense. Why does it cost 3.5x as much to add a rail? Have you discussed this with the factory? Figure out the actual issues, don't work around understanding them.

Answer (score 7):

Your assembler can answer.

The rail width of the PCB holder/gripper of the machine is a limiting factor. Even though you guarantee a 2mm distance between the board edge and the nearest component it might still be a problem when feeding the PCB to the machine's holder. Plus, the assembler may not want the PnP nozzle to approach the edge/gripper closer than some distance.

Using a custom frame is sometimes a way to go. A steel frame with an opening for the exact size of your PCB can be used for PnP, reflow and even wave soldering. But it'll be another cost, of course.

Answer (score 6):

The assembler will do the panelization for you, **they will insist!**

They cannot work with bare board as the machines and conveyors they have cannot grip them.
They also want to add fiducials and markings for their process.

You can specify hints on the documentation layers where they should or should not put breakaway tabs or if they should prefer v-groove for mousebites etc..

If your design does not allow depanelization at all due to flexing constraints, you have to find an assembler that does assembly by hand, they exist mostly for rapid prototying. However the price will go up significantly!

---

In general it is wise to orient ceramic passives in way that board flexing stress from the edges of the board doesn't go as much lengthwise through the component.
Eg: place ceramics parallel to the board edge.

There are also some tracing geometries you could apply to reduce the chances of broken solder joints. But I would be speculating if I said they would work.

Comment: check out this  its basic desktop pick and place machine but  fixture can grip the board . Isn't it impossible if the SMD components are far enough from the edges of the board?

youtu.be/OaM4Bfce-Yk?si=SIP07KfByndlbnxd&t=10

Comment: @Electronx yes, that is nice for prototypes. Same market as deltaproto microplacer.

Answer (score 3):

I work with pick and place machines on everyday basis. To answer your question: Yes, the SMD pick and place machine can work without a breakaway rail but it is not recommended to do so.

For my machine, if the clearance between the board's edge and copper features is less than 3.5mm (138mil,) or your boards need to be panelized, breakaway rails must be added to the two longer parallel edges of the boards.

Panelizing, or making a PCB with multiple boards, can sometimes be more expensive because the manufacturer needs to cut it into pieces. It depends on how the manufacturer builds the board.

If you are unsure about the build you can always contact costumer service as it is always best to consult with the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that many board assemblers prefer to use their own contractors to print the boards, and will also take your production files for a single board, then add fiducials panels, and rails before sending it on to their board printer.  They'll add exactly what they want to minimize production failures.  Yes, they charge for this (in their Non-repeating-engineering fees, or NRE's).

Sure, if you adequately communicate with your assembler during the process, you can pretty much do whatever you want, but deviations from a company's preferred work flow is often best avoided.  Surprises can always happen.

As an example, I used a board assembler that didn't want boards bigger than some particular size, as their experience was that the pick and place process created some "bounce" in the board that increased their failure rates.  They don't even talk about it to "standard" customers, because if you use their preferred workflow, there's no reason for you to know it.  If you want to do something non-standard, like panelize your own boards, you certainly do need to know about it.